# How to remove text with preg_replace function of php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the code like this:

```
$data='<p>text begin</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".idr").hide();
$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({ placement: "top"});
</script>
<p>text finish</p>';
```

I'm trying to remove below text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".idr").hide();
$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({ placement: "top"});
</script>
```

with preg_replace()

```
echo preg_replace("/<script(.+?)script>/i", '', $data);
```

But it's doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are tring to remove the script try this:

```
preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add multiline modifier:

```
echo preg_replace("/<script(.+?)script>/si", '', $data);
//                               here __^
```